# Clean an invalide xml string, to make it valide xml

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have an invalide xml file (which results from the concatenation of multiple xml files). Is it possible to clear the non desired duplicated nodes (root and xml) to go from here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Client>client1</Client>
    <ClientType>1</ClientType>
</root><?xml version="1.0">
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Client>client2</Client>
</root><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <Client>client3</Client>    
</root>
```

to here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Client>client1</Client>
    <ClientType>1</ClientType>
    <Client>client2</Client>
    <Sex>1</Sex>
    <Client>client3</Client>
    <Sex>1</Sex>
</root>
```

I've started using Regex to find occurences of "xml" and "root",

```
var test = Regex.Matches(input, "<\\?xml").Count;
```

But I have two difficulties :
1/ Delete all root nodes except first and last one. (use IndexOf function maybe ?)
2/ Manage nodes which are slighlty different, for example

```
 <root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

and

```
 <root>
```

must be treated the same way

Comment: XmlSerializer works on not validate xml files ?

Comment: A well formed XML has only on root tag.  Your XML is not well formed, but is valid according to the XML specification.  In Net library you have to use an XmlReader with following settings :             XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;  I used it an answer yesterday.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042159/error-deserializing-xml-file-into-c-sharp-class-of-objects/69043136?force_isolation=true#69043136

Comment: XML is unforgiving to well-formedness errors, so any XML-aware application is expected to reject such documents. Trying to fix parse errors on-the-fly is probably the wrong approach, and you should ask yourself if you really want or need this. XML is _not_ similar to HTML, where syntax errors are generally forgiven. XML is similar to programming code. Everything must be perfect, or it's not XML.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an XML Parser. It will let you get what you need in all those file. Then, you could create a new one with whatever data you do need inside.

You could start with : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=net-5.0

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution IMHO: read both files using an XML parser, e.g. by using 2 separate [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) objects , then [copy XML nodes over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode?view=net-5.0) as needed, and finally [write the altered object to a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.writeto).

It may not be easy, esp. when dealing with namespaces, but even then this is probably the best approach to get good, reliable results.